# Can not evaluate an object in r

Tags: r, dplyr, model, formula, eval

I have a model.

```
library(dlnm)
library(splines)
data(chicagoNMMAPS)

cb1.pm <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$pm10, lag=15, argvar=list(fun="lin"),
                     arglag=list(fun="poly",degree=4))


model1 <- glm(death ~ cb1.pm + ns(time, 7*14) + dow,
              family=quasipoisson(), chicagoNMMAPS)

pred1.pm1 <- crosspred(cb1.pm, model1, bylag=0.2, cumul=TRUE)
```

I want to use a character vector to call the object `cb1.pm` so I tried this.

```
# use character vector

i = 'pm'

cb1.var = paste0('cb1.', i) %>% get()

model2 <- glm(death ~ cb1.var + ns(time, 7*14) + dow,
              family=quasipoisson(), chicagoNMMAPS)


pred1.pm2 <- crosspred(cb1.pm, model2, bylag=0.2, cumul=TRUE) # Error occur here 

identical(cb1.pm, cb1.var) # TRUE
```

The result `identical(cb1.pm, cb1.var)` is `TURE`, but
why can't these two variables replace each other?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `crosspred` uses non-standard evaluation to extract the name of the first argument from your call and tries to match it up to the variables in `model2`. It does this using `grep`. Since you have used `cb1.var` as the name in your model, the `crosspred` function doesn't find any coefficients containing the string "cb1.pm" and throws an error.

The way round this is to ensure that `cb1.var` remains as a symbol and is substituted for `cb1.pm` before the model is built. This is also more efficient, since you don't need to copy the whole `cb1.pm` data:

```r
i = 'pm'

cb1.var = paste0('cb1.', i)

form <- as.formula(paste("death ~", cb1.var, "+  ns(time, 7*14) + dow"))

model2 <- glm(form, family = quasipoisson(), chicagoNMMAPS)

pred1.pm2 <- crosspred(cb1.pm, model2, bylag = 0.2, cumul=TRUE)
```

We no longer get a warning, and we can confirm we have the correct model:

```r
identical(pred1.pm1, pred1.pm2)
#> [1] TRUE
```